# How to redirect LLI output?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, interpreter

How can i redirect lli output (fprintf, cout) to get it as variable or make my callback executed?

I've reviewed `/tools/lli/lli.cpp` and as far as i understand the code
is executed by `ExecutionEngine` which is built by `EngineBuilder`. Can EE be configured somehow for this?

PS. I can't use lli executable launch and OS output redirection as i'm using static library with lli code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a particular hook for that. But what about just using the usual technique of redirecting file descriptors ([dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) et al), while the `ExecutionEngine` is running, and switching back when it's done?